# Problem with <title> generation on Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, title

On client's web site one big problem - i don't understand how  of all page generated. It's somehow not use a title field.

For example: http://stankosell.ru/informaciy.html (russian) use keywords in title, but not title.

In which file i can find a bug?

Comment: Can you clarify "use keywords in title, but not title." It would appear that your title includes keywords, which other field did you mean?

Comment: No. It use keywords which i don't know where it placed. I think they are automatedgenerated from text (content). How to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the extensions you have installed, some will manipulate the title tag. On a vanilla install with no SEO extensions the title tag comes from one of 2 places -

1. The title parameter in the menu item
2. The title of the article/category